# JPA 2.0 API maven artifact

Tags: maven-2, jpa-2.0

I am using JPA 2.0 and my persistence provider is Hibernate; however, I'd like to just include a standard API from javax, but in central, there is no 2.0 artifact.  I am currently using the Hibernate JPA 2.0 artifact, but I'd like to use something more standard.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Walter

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I am currently using the Hibernate JPA 2.0 artifact, but I'd like to use something more standard

There is still no `javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:2.0` artifact from Sun/Oracle. Either use the full `javax:javaee-api:jar:6.0` artifact if you want something from Sun/Oracle... or just stick with the interfaces provided by Hibernate, EclipseLink, OpenJPA, etc.

Comment: Is this still the case as of November 2010?

Comment: There's a typo: you have 'javaeee-api' (note the 3 e's), should be 'javaee-api'

Comment: Seems this is still the case here in January 2012...what gives?

Comment: Please see my answer below, with details about an official Oracle jar containing the JPA 2.0 API interfaces.

Answer (score 11):

Currently (Q1 2020) the default artifact is

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

An older artifact of `javax.persistence-api` is also available at maven central, but is superseded by the jakarta version.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The code is maintained in [this github repo](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec).

Answer (score 9):

As Ivan explains, there are no official Sunacle jars in Maven. However, it is quite often the case that an implementer of a given API will publish an artifact for that API (the API itself, rather than their implementation of it.

In the case of JPA 2.0, Hibernate publish [org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.hibernate.javax.persistence%7Chibernate-jpa-2.0-api%7C1.0.1.Final%7Cjar), which contains just the `javax.persistence` classes, and no Hibernate-specific stuff.

My build.gradle therefore says:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.0-api', version: '1.0.1.Final'
    runtime group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '4.1.4.Final'
}
```

Which puts Hibernate's release of the API on the compile classpath, and their implementation on the runtime classpath.

Comment: Every major provider seems to have their own `javax.persistence` classes.  Which is just stupid as you'd think there would be one by 2016 that is the canonical one for JPA 2.0, 2.1, etc...

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer to your questions is: No, it's not possible. The longer version is given here: [Apache > Maven > Guide to Coping with Sun JARs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-coping-with-sun-jars.html) . A short summary of the longer answer:

There are (at least) two problems with publishing Sun/Oracle artifacts in central repository:

1. Restrictive license
2. Naming convention