# Where can I find a JPA2 Maven dependency?

Tags: maven, dependencies, jpa-2.0

I'm trying to build an implementation agnostic maven module which relies on JPA2.  Unfortunately, the only Maven JPA dependency is JPA1 based, and consequently, I cannot use EntityManager.detach() method as that is a JPA2 option only.

Ideally, I'd love to be able to specify my javax.persistence dependency in my Pom, and require the app/container to supply the JPA2 implementation.  Unfortunately, I cannot find any such dependency.

Is my only choice at this point to declare hibernate-jpa-2.0-api 1.0.0.FINAL as a provided dependency?

Comment: See [first answer][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243147/jar-file-for-jpa-2-0

Comment: From what I can tell, I can use the geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec dependency as well.  But does it make a difference whether I use the geronimo or the hibernate jpa dependency?  It would seem as though it would be irrelevant if I scope it as provided.

Comment: On general principles (no experience here), I'd use one from an implementation that you're _not_ planning to use for most of your testing.  That will give you higher confidence that you're implementation-independent, strictly from a compile-time perspective.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The Hibernate JPA 2 classes (javax.persistence...) are here:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 47):

I know this is a quite old post, if you want to go agnostic from the implementation, then you should use the Java EE API dependency instead.

Just add to your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>${jee.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Where the ${jee.version} is your desired Java EE version. I'm currently using 7.0. It has all EJB, JPA and JSF APIs dependencies.

Comment: Sorry for this late question but if you use this dependency you are not able to build a working persistence.xml file as IDE like eclipse and intellij can't resolve the classes. Am I missing a point here?

Comment: If you're talking about implementation classes other than the pure API, then you won't have them. This approach is if you're working purely with the API directly. At development time, you will do have all API classes while you stick your code to the API. Any other specific implementation from any JPA provider, such as Hibernate or EclipseLink, then you'll need to add their dependencies too.

Comment: `javaee-api` still looks incomplete. I needed to add `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0` as well.

Comment: @Jarekczek, it depends. You might be mismatching the apis versions. Java EE API 7, for example, contains the Servlet API 3.1, while Java EE API 6 will contain Servlet API 3.0.

Answer (score 10):

I use the `javax.persistence` artifact (and not the `eclipselink` artifact) from the  EclipseLink Maven repository to access the JPA 2 API classes. Snippets from POM include:

```
<project>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ...
    <repositories>
        ...
        <repository>
            <id>EclipseLink Repo</id>
            <!-- note that ampersands in this URL are escaped because this is in an 
            xml file - un-escape them to use in browser -->
            <url>http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&amp;nf=1&amp;file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
        </repository>
    ...
    </repositories>
...
</project>
```

The `javax.persistence` artifact contains all the API classes, and none of the EclipseLink classes (except for two), allowing you to specify the scope as provided; this applies even for the EclipseLink JPA provider as well (which is in the `eclipselink` artifact Id).

I haven't mixed the `javax.persistence` artifact with the `hibernate-entitymanager` artifact, which is how I managed the dependency for another project that relies on Hibernate EntityManager instead of EclipseLink for the JPA provider. A snippet from the second project's POM is shown below:

```
<project>
    <dependencies>
    ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.5.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ...
</project>
```

I do change the dependency scopes from `provided` to `test` in other projects to ensure that unit tests will have a JPA provider in the classpath. This is primarily done to mask out the side-effects of using the [`javaee-api` dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979968/cant-instantiate-javax-servlet-servletexception), which I use in the parent POM to allow compile time references to several Java EE 6 API classes.

Answer (score 4):

This are the most relevant and official API for JPA2 from EclipseLink:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
        <id>eclipselink</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>Repository for library EclipseLink (JPA 2.0)</name>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Unlike Hibernates API this are from  official specification and support better generics when it comes to use Criteria API.

Comment: Why did you add the answer with scope provided?

Answer (score 3):

For the JPA 2.2 API an "official" artifact is available from maven central, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46862921/868941).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve resolve my Maven JPA2 dependency by adding a couple of dependencies to the project's pom.xml file.  See below for the xml code for the dependencies.
I found the latest groupId's and artifactId's versions by drilling down the directories out on [Maven Central](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2).  I just walked the directory tree until I found the metadata.xml files for the [persistence.core](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.core/maven-metadata.xml) and the [persistence.jpa](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa/maven-metadata.xml) artifacts.
**Note**: The dependency on [persistence.jpa](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa/maven-metadata.xml) is what actually brings in the [javax.persistence jar](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/persistence/javax.persistence/2.1.1/javax.persistence-2.1.1.jar).

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of today, I think the most up to date one is:

```
<dependency>                                          
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>    
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>                    
</dependency>
```

This is how you can use JPA in a maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```