# How to choose the proper package to import in a maven project?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, ejb, ejb-3.0, maven-3

I am using IntelliJ IDea 12 Ultimate and I have created a Maven project.
Then I created a class and I tried to add the @Entity annotation to it.
Now instead of leting me choose a local package as it does with non-maven projects, intellij idea started to asked me to import to the pom.xml some remote dependencies.
How do I know which package to choose?
When I had a non-maven project for example, I chose javax.persistence package to use and the ide added the proper import based on the underlying JDK.
Now if I go to http://mvnrepository.com/ and search for javax.persistence I get this page (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api) and I have four different things to choose (1.0-rev-1, 1.0.2, 1.0, 1.0b).
How do I know which version my JDK uses, so I can pick the proper maven dependency?
Thank you.

PS : This is what IntelliJ chose when I searched for artifact id (it seems that it chooses the latest version only, independently of the packager):

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project needs external dependencies, it means that they are not included in your JDK, so when you ask *which version my JDK uses*, it is not really relevant. I would say that "the latest is the greatest" :)

If you want to use JPA 2, see this thread: [Where can I find a JPA2 Maven dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836772/where-can-i-find-a-jpa2-maven-dependency)

You will need `javax.persistence` and another dependency for the implementation of JPA (Hibernate, toplink, OpenJPA, etc.)

Comment: If I get it right, all these packagers (eclipse, hibernate) use the same official javax.persistence implementation but the differences are that they package some extra things in their packages?

Comment: `javax.persistence` is 'only' an API, which is part of the Java EE stack. Basically it's a set of interfaces / annotations, which needs to be implemented by a provider (eclipselink being the reference implementation of JPA 2). See the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent information.One last thing, when I used it in a non-maven project, which implementation did my project use?

Comment: It depends on what jar you had in your classpath... Did your code work as expected? Do you have a `lib/` folder (or equivalent), and what does it contain?

Comment: The JDK does not contain any JPA implementation, unfortunately I can't answer your question without knowing your project's content.

Comment: I think I used the very same package, because you tell IntelliJ IDea that you want hibernate support and I am seeing the same exact jar.(hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar)

Comment: Then it's very likely that your project used Hibernate :)

Comment: Can you make a guess on why IntelliJ Idea chooses this specific implementation in a maven project?