# What is the difference between Tomcat and TomEE, TomEE and TomEE Plus

Tags: java, tomcat, server, apache-tomee

I want to deploy EJB ear in a server but I am really confused about choosing a server among `tomcat`, `TomEE` and `TomEE Plus`.

1. What are the differences between `Tomcat` and `TomEE`?
2. What are the new features in `TomEE` and `TomEE Plus`?
3. In which case(s) does it make sense to go for `TomEE` and `TomEE Plus`?

so I need some suggestions in order to be able to make an informed decision.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

This is functions comparison matrix between **[Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/)**, **[TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/)** and **[TomEE+](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html)**:
[image]
(Source: http://tomee.apache.org/comparison.html)

**1.** **Tomcat** vs **TomEE**
**Tomcat** is servlet container that supports servlet and JSP technology. **TomEE** is more extensive than **Tomcat** supporting many other Java EE technologies (specificed by JSR-xxx).

**2.** Compare **TomEE** vs **TomEE+**

> **TomEE** contains:
>  CDI - Apache
>   OpenWebBeans
>  EJB - Apache OpenEJB
>  JPA - Apache OpenJPA
>   JSF - Apache MyFaces
>  JSP - Apache Tomcat
>  JSTL - Apache
>   Tomcat
>  JTA - Apache Geronimo Transaction
>  Servlet - Apache
>   Tomcat
>  Javamail - Apache Geronimo JavaMail
>  Bean Validation -
>   Apache BVal
>   **TomEE+**
>   The TomEE Plus distribution adds the following:
>  
>   JAX-RS - Apache CXF
>  JAX-WS - Apache CXF
>  JMS - Apache
>   ActiveMQ
>  Connector - Apache Geronimo Connector

(Source: http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html)
What is new in Tomcat? Of cource, see [Tomcat change log](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_8.0.23_(markt)).
What is new in TomEE plus? see [TomEE change log](http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-1.7.2-release-notes.html).

**3.** Choose **TomEE** or **TomEE plus**?
See functions matrix at the above, pick your functions in your application what you will use. Then choose `Servlet container`/ `Web profile application server` / `Application server` by yourself.

Comment: Can you help me to clear out a thing, the term of support here whether it is the application server will provide the library for example JPA with OpenJPA as it's implementation or more than, for example with Tomcat which doesn't support JPA, so we can't use Hibernate which is another implementation of JPA ?

Comment: You can use JPA with Apache Tomcat (I am sure 100%), you need add JPA-implement dependency into your application. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7230084/3728901

Answer (score 15):

Apache Tomcat is a Java servlet container which implements the following specifications:

1. Java Servlet Specification
2. Java ServerPages (JSP)
3. Expression Language (EL)
4. WebSocket

The version of Tomcat you choose will dictate the versions of the above specifications that are supported.

Apache TomEE is a Java EE Web Profile-certified stack which is built on top of an Apache Tomcat base integrated with additional related technologies. It adds implementations for the following specifications (using the Apache project shown in parentheses):

1. CDI - Apache OpenWebBeans
2. EJB - Apache OpenEJB
3. JPA - Apache OpenJPA
4. JSF - Apache MyFaces
5. JSP - Apache Tomcat
6. JSTL - Apache Tomcat
7. JTA - Apache Geronimo Transaction
8. Servlet - Apache Tomcat
9. Javamail - Apache Geronimo JavaMail
10. Bean Validation - Apache BVal

Apache TomEE+ adds:

1. JAX-RS - Apache CXF
2. JAX-WS - Apache CXF
3. JMS - Apache ActiveMQ
4. Connector - Apache Geronimo Connector

Note that all of this was available from some obvious places on these Apache web sites:

- [Apache TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html)
- [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)

If I understand correctly, the whole EAR thing has been abandoned in favor of good-old WAR files. But, if you have to deploy an EAR file, you are more than likely going to require Apache TomEE. Apache Tomcat certainly doesn't know what the heck to do with an EAR file.