# OpenEJB 8 usage

Tags: ejb, java-11, openejb

I'm seeking to upgrade an existing EJB-based (EJB lite-based?) application to Java 11, using an embedded EJB container.  I would try TomEE Embedded Server 8, however I can't find its GA release or release date.  But [OpenEJB Server](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomee/openejb-server) is allegedly in GA and [claims to support EJBs](http://tomee.apache.org/comparison.html) and it accepts [configuration parameters](http://tomee.apache.org/properties-listing.html) and indicates that my application is loaded, however no services are bound to any ports.  Where can I find an SSCCE for OpenEJB 8?

```
Feb 06, 2020 1:44:51 PM org.apache.openejb.util.LogStreamAsync run
INFO: Assembling app: ...\apps\myapp.jar
Feb 06, 2020 1:44:51 PM org.apache.openejb.util.LogStreamAsync run
INFO: Assembling app: ...\bin\scheduled\classpath.ear
Feb 06, 2020 1:44:51 PM org.apache.openejb.util.LogStreamAsync run
INFO: Deployed Application(path=...\bin\scheduled\classpath.ear)
[init] OpenEJB Remote Server
Feb 06, 2020 1:44:52 PM org.apache.openejb.util.LogStreamAsync run
INFO:   ** Bound Services **
Feb 06, 2020 1:44:52 PM org.apache.openejb.util.LogStreamAsync run
INFO:   NAME                 IP              PORT  
Feb 06, 2020 1:44:52 PM org.apache.openejb.util.LogStreamAsync run
INFO: -------
Feb 06, 2020 1:44:52 PM org.apache.openejb.util.LogStreamAsync run
INFO: Ready!
```

Comment: As it stands your question is broad, and needs more focus (_"edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once"_). Perhaps it might be better to focus just on detailing the specific problem(s) you are having with OpenEJB 8, particularly since you appear to have eliminated alternative approaches already? Even if you can't provide a simple example, you can still describe the error(s) you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, now I feel foolish... [TomEE was released September 2019](https://whimsy.apache.org/board/minutes/TomEE.html).  Given [some guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535565/what-is-the-difference-between-tomcat-and-tomee-tomee-and-tomee-plus) I can hopefully figure out how to use that even if it's more than I need and I find its documentation confusing.

I couldn't find this GA the other day, but here it is:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomee/tomee-embedded